# Having issues declaring a swift dictionary variable

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to store some colors in a dictionary so they are easy to reach. My problem was that xcode stucks when indexing this dictionary. I found out that splitting the dictionary into multiple parts solves this error.
But i can not add any more items.

```
var flatColors = ["turquoise" : UIColor(0x1ABC9C)]
flatColors["green"] = UIColor(0x2ECC71)
```

The error message i get at the moment at the second line says "Expressions are not allowed at the top level"

Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're not using Playgrounds and your code isn't inside a function.

Let me elaborate: your `flatColors` dictionary definition is allowed to be outside a function and doing so will create you a global variable. But you're not allowed to use `flatColors["green"] = UIColor(0x2ECC71)` outside a function. For example, this **is** allowed:

```
var flatColors = ["turquoise" : UIColor(0x1ABC9C)]

func editColors() {
    flatColors["green"] = UIColor(0x2ECC71)
}
```

Comment: Ohh that's why! Thank you ver much